# AWS- Associating a VPC with load balancer creation using boto API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, boto, amazon-vpc

I am relatively new to automating with boto and have created a script which sets up an auto scaling infrastructure on AWS using python's boto API.

However, I am unable to associate my VPC with my load balancer creation. The following code returns a Malformed Input error:

```
zoneStrings = 'eu-west-1a', 'eu-west-1b' #The availability zones of my VPC
elb_conn = boto.ec2.elb.connect_to_region('eu-west-1') #

lb_name = 'my-lb'
zones = zoneStrings
subnets = 'subnet-09519f50', 'subnet-9fa12dfa' #VPC subnets
ports= [(80, 80, 'http'), (443, 443, 'tcp')]
lb = elb_conn.create_load_balancer(lb_name, zones, subnets, ports)
```

The error in full is :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 70, in <module>
    lb = elb_conn.create_load_balancer(lb_name, zones, subnets, ports)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/elb/__init__.py", line 243, in create_load_balancer
    params, LoadBalancer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1207, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-06-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MalformedInput</Code>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>12659703-a021-11e4-9488-1f8ceceab6a1</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The boto documentation states that the order of parameters to the `create_load_balancer` method is:

- name
- zones
- listeners
- subnets
- ...

You seem to be supplying them in a different order.  Perhaps the safest approach is to use keyword arguments rather than relying on positional order.  So:

```
lb = elb_conn.create_load_balancer(name=lb_name, zones=zones, subnets=subnets, listeners=ports)
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your help : The following worked                                         lb = elb_conn.create_load_balancer(name=lb_name, zones=zones, subnets=subnets, listeners=ports, security_groups=sg).                                  Curiously, the documentation order is listeners before subnets, which would not work for me. http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/elb.html#boto.ec2.elb.ELBConnection.create_load_balancer

Comment: Also, the value of zones has to be none, or it causes a conflict with the vpc subnets.